# Applescript path of a file in the active application

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to run an applescript to get the path of the file in the active app (ex; a PDF document I'm viewing with Preview).

I tried this, which displays the path of the document as expected:

```
tell application "Preview"
    set mypath to path of front document
end tell
display dialog(mypath)
```

The problem is when I try to use a variable name to access the active application. The following displays 'Preview' (without quotations) correctly:

```
tell application "System Events" 
    set activeApp to name of first application process whose frontmost is true
end tell
display dialog(activeApp)
```

However, when I try to combine both blocks, I can't get it to work at all, even inside Preview.

```
tell application "System Events" 
    set activeApp to name of first application process whose frontmost is true
end tell

tell application activeApp
    set mypath to path of front document
end tell

display dialog(mypath)
```

Doesn't display anything in dialog.

I am aware that different applications have different ways of specifying what the "current document" is, but why wouldn't this work on a single app is beyond me. I'm also very new to Applescripts, so maybe someone with more experience can see the mistake?

Comment: Welcome to AppleScript.  That is just the way it works - applications can (and usually do) use different terminology, and some may not even be scriptable.  Your combination script works for me from the Script Menu with Preview (assuming it has an open document) - how are you launching your script?

Comment: I don’t see the mistake; in fact, when I save the third, combined, script inside Preview’s Script Menu folder, it displays the path to the topmost PDF document. You may want to be more detailed about what you mean by “even inside Preview”. (I can get it to not display the path if the frontmost PDF doesn’t have a path. I.e., by copying a page of an existing pdf and doing “New from Clipboard”.)

Comment: You are right, it does seem to work directly when calling it from the script editor. I do get the path to the actual script.
 I tried calling it different ways (Automator, Shortcuts, Terminal, Alfred) and they all fail, no matter what app I'm on. It does work with the Script Menu.

I will keep trying to find a solution as it was pretty important for me to be able to call this script quickly. In the meantime, I'm glad I wasn't going crazy for thinking this script should work!

Comment: You may want to be more specific about what you want to happen when you call it from outside Preview, since the “first application process” then is likely to be either the script itself (if it’s an app) or the application you’re calling it from (i.e., Terminal). Step by step, what is it you want to do, what actually happens, and what you *want* to have happened that is different?